# Find a string after a special character, move it and wrap a div around it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code, for example:

```
<div class="new">
 <div class="in"></div>
 <label>some text now watch this | the-thing</label>
</div>
```

I want to:

1. find the text thats after the "|" character
2. move it outside the label
3. wrap a span tag around it

I know how to do the 2nd and 3rd part, but I don't understand how to manipulate the string to begin with.

Comment: Well, there's [`.substring()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).

Comment: There's also `.split()`, which you can split on a regex.  Question what if you have something like `some text | to split | and some more`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to get/replace the text. Then create a span element and append it after the label.

```
var str = $( "div.new label" ).html();
var match = str.match( /\|(.*)/ )[1];
$( "div.new label" ).html( str.replace( /\|(.*)/, "" ) );
$( "div.new" ).append( "<span>" + match + "</span>" );
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4m9AX/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TaDKp/.

```
var re = /\|\s*(.*)$/;
var o = $(".new label");
var match = o.text().match(re);
if (match) {
    o.text(o.text().replace(re, ""));
    o.after("<span class='special'>" + match[1] + "</span>");
}
```

The steps described:

1. Find the desired label object
2. Find the text in the text of the label object using a regular expression
3. If the text is found, remove it from the label
4. Insert a span with that text after the label

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript regular expressions to capture and replace the text after the special character. Read about the standard RegExp class.

Answer (score 0):

To do the first part you need to access the content of the label. Do that using jQuery. Something like:

```
$(".new > label").val();
```

And then to get the text after the "|" character, what you need is two javascript functions: [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use indexOf() to find the text after the character

```
var str = $('.new label').text();
var strToMove = str.substring(str.indexOf('|') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write the code, but here is probably how you should go about it:

1: Add an id to the label e.g.   `<label id="originaltext">`
2. In your javascript, assign a variable to:    `document.getElementById("originaltext").innerText;`
3. Use [string.split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to split the text using the '|' character into 2 variables
4. Set the contents of the original div to the text before the pipe using: `document.getElementById("originaltext").innerText = stringbeforepipe`
5. Set the contents of the new div using the same method except using the variable storing the string after the seperator.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the final html snippet to be

```
<div class="new">
 <div class="in"></div>
 <span>the-thing</span>
 <label>some text now watch this</label>
</div>
```

?

The jquery would look something like this:

```
var node = $('label').contains('|').

var txt =  node.val();
var newtxt = txt.substr(0, txt.indexOf('|')-1);
var cuttxt = txt.substr(txt.indexOf('|')+);
node.before('<span>'' + cuttxt + '</span>');
node.text(newtxt);
```

Not test, probably won't work, YMMV, etc...

Answer (score -3):

You can get the string thus:

```
var str = $('div.new label').text();
```

Then use string primitives to slice the bit of the string you want.